# Random Generator Questions

Tags: c#

How do i make a application that will produce a random number between 1-10 and then ask the user to guess that number, and if that number is matching the random number tell them if they got it right!

I'm a student, like super new and was out of class for a few days because of surgery and i can not figure this out for the life of me!

This is what i've come up with for the problem.

```
namespace GuessingGame
{
   class Program
   {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int min = 1;
            int max = 10;    
            Random ranNumberGenerator = new Random();
            int randomNumber;
            randomNumber = ranNumberGenerator.Next(min, max);
            Console.WriteLine("Guess a random number between 1 and 10.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            if (randomNumber == randomNumber)
                Console.WriteLine("You got it!");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry, try again!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: You're not actually reading and parsing their input, you're trying to compare the computer's random number to itself.

Comment: I can't figure out what their input is labeled as!

Comment: +1 for clearly stating that it's an assignment, and showing exactly what you have tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The upper limit for the `Next` method is exclusive, so you want to use 11 rather than 10 for that:

```
randomNumber = ranNumberGenerator.Next(min, max + 1);
```

You are ignoring the input from the user. Capture that in a string:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
```

Then parse the input to a number:

```
int number = Int32.Parse(input);
```

Now you can compare that number to the random number.

---

If you want to handle incorrect input from the user in a more user friendly way than crashing, you would use `TryParse` to attempt to parse the number.

Comment: Okay, A little confused sorry. I've got it all set up "I think" but i keep getting an issue saying that randomNumber cant be used with == now.

Comment: Are you comparing the integers, i.e. `number == randomNumber`?

Comment: I got it thank you guffa you were a big help. also what exactly was + 1 for? does that include 10 ? where as before it did not?

Comment: @user3314948: Yes, to get a random number from 1 to 10 inclusive, you use `.Next(1, 11)`. Keeping the `max` variable as it is and adding one to the value when calling `Next` makes more sense than changing `max` to 11, as the exclusive upper boundary is a characteristic of the `Next` method.

Answer (score 0):

You're close but you need to store the user answer. The way you have will always return true.

```
var guess = Console.ReadLine();
```

Then you can compare

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(guess) == randomNumber)
```

At the end I would also suggest something like `Console.ReadKey()` or the program will finish and exit before you can see the result.

Note this assumes correct input, you always want to implement some sort of error handling as well in case the user types something other than an integer.

Comment: Its now saying randomnumber isnt a int for ===

Comment: @user3314948 Look at Guffas answer, he actually explains how to convert to int as well. I also edited my answer to show another way